# Maven projects is hidden automatically java 21

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-17, java-21

The Maven project is getting hidden (along with source) automatically when I try to clean/build the maven project in IntelliJ Idea.

I have added the video here: https://youtu.be/rrEDXrFCvmY

Before clicking on clean install

[image: Before clean install]

After clicking on clean install

[image: After clean install]

Any suggessions are much appreciated.

IntelliJ version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 8000M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.properties.bundle.editor (223.7571.203)
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (223.8214.6)
    PMDPlugin (1.8.27)
    ink.organics.pojo2json (2.0.4)
    net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (3.0.2-223)
    camtwoTomcatRunner (1.7)
    com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat (4.3.8)
    com.bigmy (1.0)
    ChatGPT (2.1.10-222.231)
    com.ld.chatGPT-copilot (0.5.4)
    com.intellij.lang.jsgraphql (3.3.0)
    appland.appmap (0.42.1)
    SequenceDiagram (2.2.6)
    zielu.gittoolbox (213.10.5)
    org.sonarlint.idea (7.3.0.59206)
    aws.toolkit (1.67-223)

Kotlin: 223-1.7.21-release-272-IJ8214.52
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mapping</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mappingapi-Jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Mappingapi-Jwt</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It looks like clean is deleting all your project sources. In the 2nd image, all the project sources are gone. Probably, your POM is misconfigured and clean is deleting the POM, which makes IntelliJ think it's no longer a Maven project, since all valid Maven projects have a POM. You should show your POM.

Comment: @Michael It is not deleting the files. They are added back if I just update any javac settings.

Comment: Show the POM anyway

Comment: @Michael, updated pom.xml in question

Comment: First suggestion upgrade your IntelliJ version?

Comment: thank you @khmarbaise Do you advise any particular version

Comment: Most recent version of IntelliJ IDEA always do the updates are provided...

Comment: It is working but still plays hide and Seek after installing . Let me make video. Something strange. `Version`: `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 (Community Edition)`

Comment: Here is the current state: https://youtu.be/xif4ipscnzE

Comment: 1. Execute the command via a separate Terminal and validate the experience IntelliJ. This would help you narrow down the cause of the issue. 2. Validate if any of your plugins configured on the IDE could be the cause or are trying to perform some resource management over the project directory. 3. Do share the repo link for folks to be able to reproduce the issue, once you are able to confirm the direction to look into.

Comment: Click on the "test[Mappingapi-JWT" in upper left corner and that contains the tree with the sources etc..

Comment: This kind of behavior typically happens when IDEA cannot resolve the Project. Which Maven version and JDK your Project uses? Does the Project Import / Maven Sync work as intended?